# how to drop table in database ? and how to create view table?

Tags: database, oracle

how to make views from all tables already exist in database that’s hard task to catch the tables one by one and make create view XXXX as select * from Table_name .I find something that it is possible with cursor

,and i don't know how to create a view table in database ?

drop in database, view table in database .

Comment: what exactly are you asking for ? it is really impossible to understand,. do you want to create views for all your tables in one schema ? what is drop in database ?? what is a view table ?

Comment: And exactly _why_ would you think it desirable to create a view " from all tables already exist in database"?

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to understand what you are asking for. So assuming

- You want to create views for all your tables with names as V_<<table_name>>
- Only for one schema
- The user/schema has the privilege `create view`
- A view is a logical construction, basically a query embedded in an object, not a table, and there is no such thing as view table.
- drop a table is done by the command of the same name: `drop table <<owner>>.<<table_name>>`

Although I don't really understand why anyone would like to do this, using PLSQL is rather easy

```
declare
v_owner varchar2(40) := 'MY_SCHEMA' 
v_view  varchar2(128);
v_sql   varchar2(4000);
begin
for h in ( select table_name from all_tables where owner = v_owner order by table_name desc )
loop
    v_view := 'V_'||h.table_name ;
    v_sql := ' create or replace force view '||v_view||' as select * from '||h.table_name||' ';
    execute immediate v_sql ; 
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Right; except that exception you wrote is pretty much usless.

Comment: @Littlefoot, you are right as usual. I think it is my habit ;)